# Check is text valid javascript using javascript without using eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

Is there any way to do this? Or limit execution time of `eval()`(e.g. not more then 1 scecond)

Comment: What about JSLint? why do you need to do such a thing?

Comment: @gdoron it seems heavy for my task. Only thing I need is to check is JS valid. I'll use it if there is no anything lite for this.

Comment: Are aware of the risks with `eval`? those should bother you a lot more than the execution time of it.

Comment: In my case this JS will be avaliable only for user who write it. So there is no sequrity risks

Comment: So why won't you use: `try{eval(foo);}catch(e){alert(3);}`? Seems to be valid here if you only want to know it's valid or not.

Comment: I use this now. But if there is big loop in js?

Comment: Then use JSLint... you know the options, you just need to chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the minifiers, such as [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).  They all include a parser which might be fairly easy to extract (UglifyJS contains a file called "parse-js.js", although I haven't looked at it in detail).